# Why i am getting on Server

Tags: php

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
   '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/raphf.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/raphf.so: 
    cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
  '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/propro.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/propro.so:
```

cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly saying what the error is. It can't open the libraries. Those libraries either dont exist in that folder or apache doesnt have the right to read them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `propro` and `raph` php extensions.

On Centos you'd do something like this

```
yum install php-raphf
yum install php-propro
```

For Ubuntu use `apt-get`

```
apt-get install php-raphf
apt-get install php-propro
```

Comment: then make sure that the `.so` files are in the right path, if they have been installed in different locations, you can make a symlink to the path where php is looking for them

Comment: All are on right path and permissions are working fine as well.

Comment: Well, it's `apt-get install php5-raphf php5-propro` in Debian, and you should load raphf before propro by renaming ini links in `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/` to something like `10-raphf.ini` and `15-propro.ini`